# How to avoid timelapse when capture a video with gocv

Tags: opencv, go

I want to capture and save a videofile in mjpeg and set the resolution to 1920x1080p. The capturing works fine when i dont specialize the resolution, i can record and play it with 30fps. But if i change the recorded image size, i get a timelapse. The webcam records multiple times as long as it should and put the whole captured time into the desired video length. For an example, the webcam is supposed to record 120 frames with 30fps, so the video capture should last 4 seconds as well as the video length recorded. Instead the capturing lasts about 20sec. And the whole 20secs are in the 4secs, which gives a timelapse. How can i avoid that? Did i used wrong commands for defining the resolution? Here is my code, i already experimented with "webcam.Set(3, 1920)" etc as well as gocv.NewMat() or NewMatWithSize(...).  The following is my code

```
/*-------------------------------------------- savevideotest.go -----
|
|  Created  -
|
|  Version 1.0  2021-01-03      Initial version
|------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Version -    -               -
|------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Purpose:     Video capture tool
|               Video Capture Tool to be used as main tool when it comes
|               to recording videos with the raspberry pi
*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "gocv.io/x/gocv"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "time"
    "github.com/op/go-logging"
    "os"
)
var(
    videolength = 120       //videolength in frames (recording with 25fps). 15k = 10min
    framecheck [2]int
    videoformat *string
    location  *string
    camcount *int
    path *string
    log = logging.MustGetLogger("example")
    format = logging.MustStringFormatter(`%{color} %{time:2006:Jan:2:15:04:05.000} %{shortfunc} > %{level:.4s} %{id:03x}%{color:reset} %{message}`) // Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006 )
)



/*-------------------------------------------- init -----
|  Function init
|  Created      01.03.2021 - 
|  Last change  -- / ---- - --
|  Purpose:     Initialize flags for usage in other functions by parsing
|  Parameters:  ---
|  Returns:     ---
*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
func init()  {
    videoformat = flag.String("videoformat",".avi","desired video format")
    location = flag.String("location", "BU_", "location of raspberry pi")
    camcount = flag.Int("camcount",1,"number of used cams")
    path = flag.String("path","","sets the path of videofile")
}

/*-------------------------------------------- main -----
|  Function main
|  Created      01.03.2021 - 
|  Last change  -- / ---- - --
|  Purpose:     main function, creating infinite recording loop
|               with error control(var framecheck) and log generation
|  Parameters:  ---
|  Returns:     ---
*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
func main() {

    flag.Parse()

    printHeader()

    for {

        savevideo(videolength)
        //fmt.Printf("%v\n",framecheck)

        for k:= 0; k < *camcount; k++ {
            if framecheck[k] != videolength {
                fmt.Printf("Webcam %v hat nicht die geforderte Videolänge aufgenommen! Das Programm wird terminiert.", k)
                writeVideoLog(k)
                writeErrorLog(k)
                return
            }else {
                //framecheck[k] = 0
                writeVideoLog(k)
            }
        }

    }

}

/*-------------------------------------------- generateFileName -----
|  Function AddItem
|  Created      01.03.2021 -
|  Last change  -- / ---- - --
|  Purpose:     Function to generate the desired Filename by using flags
|  Parameters:  deviceID int
|  Returns:     filename.String
*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
func generateFileName(j int) string {

    flag.Parse()


    var filename strings.Builder
    filename.WriteString(*path)
    filename.WriteString(*location)
    filename.WriteString("__")
    filename.WriteString("Cam")
    filename.WriteString(strconv.Itoa(j))
    filename.WriteString("__")
    filename.WriteString(time.Now().Format("20060102_150405"))
    filename.WriteString(*videoformat)
    return filename.String()
}



/*-------------------------------------------- saveVideo -----
|  Function saveVideo
|  Created      01.03.2021 -
|  Last change  -- / ---- - --
|  Purpose:     Function to record and save the video
|  Parameters:  videolength int
|  Returns:     ---
*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
func savevideo(videolength int) {

    flag.Parse()


    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(*camcount)


    for j := 0; j < *camcount; j++ {

        go func(j int) {

            defer wg.Done()


            deviceID := j
            saveFile := generateFileName(j)


            webcam, err := gocv.VideoCaptureDevice(deviceID)//  OpenVideoCapture(deviceID)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Error opening video capture device: %v\n", deviceID)
                return
            }


            defer webcam.Close()

            img := gocv.NewMatWithSize(1280, 720, gocv.MatTypeCV64F)
            defer img.Close()

            webcam.Set(3, 1280)
            webcam.Set(4, 780)


            if ok := webcam.Read(&img); !ok {
                fmt.Printf("Cannot read device %v\n", deviceID)
                return
            }



            writer, err := gocv.VideoWriterFile(saveFile, "MJPG", 30, 1280, 720, true)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("error opening video writer device: %v\n", saveFile)
                return
            }
            defer writer.Close()

            fmt.Printf("%v  %v  ", img.Cols(), img.Rows())

            for i := 0; i < videolength; i++ {
                if ok := webcam.Read(&img); !ok {
                    fmt.Printf("Device closed: %v\n", deviceID)
                    return
                }
                if img.Empty() {

                    continue
                }
                framecheck[j]++
                writer.Write(img)
            }

        }(j)

    }
    wg.Wait()

}

/*-------------------------------------------- printHeader -----
|  Function printHeader
|  Created      01.03.2021 -
|  Last change  -- / ---- - --
|  Purpose:     Function to print the header of the logfile
|  Parameters:  ---
|  Returns:     ---
*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
func printHeader() {
    flag.Parse()
    file, err := os.OpenFile("logs.txt", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    backend1 := logging.NewLogBackend(file, "", 0)
    backend2 := logging.NewLogBackend(file, "", 0)
    // For messages written to backend2 we want to add some additional
    // information to the output, including the used log level and the name of
    // the function.
    backend2Formatter := logging.NewBackendFormatter(backend2, format)

    // Only errors and more severe messages should be sent to backend1
    backend1Leveled := logging.AddModuleLevel(backend1)
    backend1Leveled.SetLevel(logging.ERROR, "")

    // Set the backends to be used.
    logging.SetBackend(backend1Leveled, backend2Formatter)

    log.Info("|---------------|--------|---------------------------\n")
    log.Info("|BUSA VIDEO LOG |        |\n")
    log.Info("|---------------|--------|---------------------------\n")
    log.Info("|LOG SETUP      | INFO   | ROTATIONSIZE    800000000  [KBytes]]\n")
    log.Info("|               |        | Maximum size of Video directory\n")
    log.Info("|               |        | before old videos get deleted\n")
    log.Info("|               |--------|---------------------------\n")
    log.Info("|               | INFO   | MaxFileSizeLOG  500  [KBytes]\n")
    log.Info("|               |        | Maximum size of Logfile\n")
    log.Info("|               |        | before old logfiles get copied\n")
    log.Info("|               |        | away to BUSA_VIDEO.log.TIMESTAMP\n")
    log.Info("|               |--------|---------------------------\n")
    log.Info("|               | INFO   | MaxNumOldLOGS  10\n")
    log.Info("|               |        | Maximum number of old Logfiles\n")
    log.Info("|               |        | before oldest logfile get deleted\n")
    log.Info("|---------------|--------|---------------------------\n")
    log.Info("|LOCATION SETUP | INFO   | LOCATION_NAME " + *location + "\n")
    log.Info("|               |        | Name of Location\n")
    log.Info("|               |        | Used in filename\n")
    log.Info("|               |--------|---------------------------\n")
    log.Info("|               | INFO   | OBJECT_ID  1500021BU027-542~~~~~\n")
    log.Info("|               |        | ID for MQTT Topic to identify Object\n")
    log.Info("|               |        | where video are recorded\n")
    log.Info("|---------------|--------|---------------------------\n")
    log.Info("|MQTT SETUP     | INFO   | localIP  10.170.63.11\n")
    log.Info("|               |        | IP Addr that get used\n")
    log.Info("|               |        | in MQTT message for URL of Video\n")
    log.Info("|               |--------|---------------------------\n")
    log.Info("|               | INFO   | BUSA_MQTT_BROKER\n")
    log.Info("|               |        | MQTT Broker\n")
    log.Info("|               |--------|---------------------------\n")
    log.Info("|               | INFO   | BOX_ID  70820e1224c5\n")
    log.Info("|               |        | Hardware ID derived from MAC-Addr\n")
    log.Info("|---------------|--------|---------------------------\n")

}

/*-------------------------------------------- writeErrorLog -----
|  Function writeErrorLog
|  Created      01.03.2021 - 
|  Last change  -- / ---- - --
|  Purpose:     Function to print an error log entry in case something wents wrong
|  Parameters:  deviceID
|  Returns:     ---
*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
func writeErrorLog(k int)  {
    flag.Parse()
    file, err := os.OpenFile("logs.txt", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    backend1 := logging.NewLogBackend(file, "", 0)
    backend2 := logging.NewLogBackend(file, "", 0)
    // For messages written to backend2 we want to add some additional
    // information to the output, including the used log level and the name of
    // the function.
    backend2Formatter := logging.NewBackendFormatter(backend2, format)

    // Only errors and more severe messages should be sent to backend1
    backend1Leveled := logging.AddModuleLevel(backend1)
    backend1Leveled.SetLevel(logging.ERROR, "")

    // Set the backends to be used.
    logging.SetBackend(backend1Leveled, backend2Formatter)

    log.Error("              | ERROR  | Kritischer Fehler: Webcam " + strconv.Itoa(k) + " hat nicht die erforderliche Anzahl an Frames aufgenommen. Die Anwendung wurde beendet.\n")

}

/*-------------------------------------------- writeVideoLog -----
|  Function writeVideoLog
|  Created      01.03.2021 -
|  Last change  -- / ---- - --
|  Purpose:     Function to write an info log entry when a video is saved
|  Parameters:  deviceID
|  Returns:     ---
*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
func writeVideoLog(k int)  {
    flag.Parse()

    file, err := os.OpenFile("logs.txt", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    backend1 := logging.NewLogBackend(file, "", 0)
    backend2 := logging.NewLogBackend(file, "", 0)
    // For messages written to backend2 we want to add some additional
    // information to the output, including the used log level and the name of
    // the function.
    backend2Formatter := logging.NewBackendFormatter(backend2, format)

    // Only errors and more severe messages should be sent to backend1
    backend1Leveled := logging.AddModuleLevel(backend1)
    backend1Leveled.SetLevel(logging.ERROR, "")

    // Set the backends to be used.
    logging.SetBackend(backend1Leveled, backend2Formatter)

    log.Info("              | INFO   | Neues Video " + generateFileName(k) + "\n")
}
```

Oh yeah, and im new to Coding, especially to Golang. Im learning Java since a month but working at a go project at work as a trainee to get a feeling for what being a developer is about.
(PS: I hope deadprogram sees this, he seems to be a god in golang and gocv, he is under EVERY single question i looked up till now :D)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the FPS with

```
webcam.Set(5, 30)
```

With 5 being the FPS flag.